# Wordpress - custom plugin not displayed on admin panle

Tags: php, wordpress

I just installed Wordpress and run on local machine everything works fine.

So I created one custom plugin under `wp-content/plugins`  folder as like this:

```
<?php 
    /*
    Plugin Name: Lottery
    Description: Plugin for displaying products from an OSCommerce shopping cart database
    */

?>
```

So then I run the admin panel in my system the created plugin is not listed on plugins section in my administration

I do not know why its not display custom plugin. Could anyone help me out where I done the mistake or anything I want to import to display my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To display your plugin name in admin panel you have to give the following code:

```
    <?php 
        /*
        Plugin Name: Lottery
        Description: Plugin for displaying products from an OSCommerce shopping cart database
        */

    add_action('admin_menu', 'function_name');

    function function_name(){
       add_menu_page( 'page_title', 'menu_title', 'capability', 'menu_slug', 'function1' );
    }
    function function1(){
           /* Plugin Code */
    }
        ?>
```

Get more details from here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

Comment: Hi sandra is it necessary to do write this function.

Comment: Which function??

Comment: add_action('admin_menu', 'function_name');

    function function_name(){
       add_menu_page( 'page_title', 'menu_title', 'capability', 'menu_slug', 'function1' );
    }
    function function1(){
           /* Plugin Code */
    }

Comment: It is used to display plugin name in admin menu and is required if you want to display plugin in menu

Comment: no i dont want to display in menu bar i just want to display it under plugins

Comment: Ok. Usually for listing the plugin only the about code you have given is enough. May be your issue will be related with the file permission. Change plugin folder permission and try.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path where you are trying to add your plugin is correct

you can create a new folder inside plugin to make it more specific

then add a php file with same name to identify it more clearly

Add the following file and it you will be done.

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Your plugin name
   Plugin URI: Your plugin url
   Description: Here goes the description
   Version: 1.0
   Author: Author name
  */

  // No direct file access
  ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
?>
```

Comment: Just create a folder for example adc inside wp-content/plugins 
inside that folder create a file with same name and add the above code inside that file

if still not working then you must have permission issue .check that and you will be good to go

thank you.